# Is it Bad That Homebuilders Used Plywood to Connect Joists and Supports in Crawlspace?

Tags: foundation, crawlspace

My wife and have recently had to be in and out of our crawlspace to thaw some pipes. She noticed the usage of plywood to connect Joists to supports. Is this normal? House was built in 2001, but we've only been here for a year.
[image]

Comment: It is normal to use wood gussets.  That is OSB instead of plywood, two different types of sheeting, but similar use purposes.

Comment: Don't you think they could have at least cut them into a T-shape, to match the post/beam connection?

Comment: @SteveSh Why? Cosmetics are not really a thought in a crawl space and a T shape would be weaker.

Comment: @SteveSh   Plus four extra cuts per piece and two waste pieces to get rid of per piece.  One post not matter much, a few hundred posts tends to add up.

Comment: Had I been doing those I would have used a trapezoidal shape - but only because I would have preferred the look of it.

Comment: Are you in an earthquake prone zone?

Comment: @SteveSh takes longer to cut a T-shape than a square, and because the guy isn't going to bother taking too much care to make cuts, you're gonna end up with waste material anyway.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate no

Comment: Should be fine, then. Check annually for shifting or looseness.